# Truffle "TypeError: Cannot read property 'legacyAST' of undefined"

Tags: solidity, truffle, contract-debugging, truffle-migration, truffle-compile

I had just finished editing what seems like the last of my error in my contracts because truffle will get to the last contract I have to compile, hangs for a second and the does this:

```
Compiling ./pathTo/x.sol...
Compiling ./pathTo/x.sol...
Compiling ./pathTo/x.sol...
/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:90035
    ast: standardOutput.sources[source_path].legacyAST,


TypeError: Cannot read property 'legacyAST' of undefined
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:90035:49
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:90026:34
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at compile (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:90023:26)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:90157:5
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:59075:7
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:59169:7
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:91073:16
    at next (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:95365:18)
```

My truffle and solc versions are:

```
Truffle v3.4.9 (core: 3.4.8)
Solidity v0.4.15 (solc-js)
```

I have never seen 'legacyAST' referred to nor has searching it returned any results. Has any else experienced this or knows what may be the cause?

Answer (score 1):

That property was required by SOLC compilers lower or equal to version 0.4.8 as it is explained at this Truffle [Github issue](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/1679)

Modify your solidity code and the `truffle-config.json` to use at least version 0.4.9.

I hope that answer solves your problem. It did to me